# What is the theano equivalent of tensorflow.reduce_sum?

Tags: tensorflow, sum, theano

Usually I look up Theano equivalent of something in Tensorflow, it comes right up. But for `reduce_sum`, nothing showed up. Can someone show me how to do `reduce_sum` in Theano?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`theano.tensor.sum()`](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/library/tensor/basic.html#theano.tensor.sum):

```py
from theano import tensor as T

x = ...
T.sum(x)
```

Comment: Thank you. Indeed that was it.